# How do I eliminate all TCP ACK retransmissions with communication to my Linux server daemon on Petalinux 2020.2 kernel

Tags: tcp, embedded, embedded-linux, xilinx, petalinux

I am working with Petalinux 2020.2 kernel and have a Linux daemon running. The Linux daemon takes in connection requests and packets asking for it to read hardware data from the part. When it has the read the information it returns a TCP packet with the information in it back to the machine that made the request via TCP.

I have already changed all the setsocket calls to have the argument TCPQUICKACK and pass in the value of 1 to enable quick ack. I also have changed the Linux Kernel Image that on bootup it sets the ip route of the ethernet port we use for external communication with the option QUICKACK and set the value to 1, which is supposed to force that ethernet port TCP communication to always use TCP QUCIK ACK for all packets.

The issue I am running into is that I still see TCP delayed ACK packets coming from my Petalinux 2020.2 kernel on my part when I observe the network traffic using WireShark. Is there another way to force QUICK ACK for all TCP packets?

I have tried setting the ip route setting of quickack to 1, which I was informed from Xilinx customer support should set it globally on that ethernet port/ip address on my Xilinx part.

Comment: Does the behavior change if you disable selective acknowledgement (i.e. set ` tcp_sack` to 0)? I notice selective acknowledgement has some extra properties associated to compressing and delaying them

Comment: Hi EmilioPeju,
Thanks for suggesting that. I turned it off the TCP_SACK by writing 0 to the /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_sack file and still had the same behavior.